# IF statement in SQL condition

Tags: mysql, if-statement, join

I tried with many solutions found through this site but still can't find a good one to fix my issue.

I would like to list all records from `warehouse_devices`, but when it's possible I need to get additional data from `devices` (when it's possible to join both tables). I have special field, `warehouse_devices`.`install`=1 means that there's an corresponding record in `devices` table.

I tried with IF statements, CASEs, etc. but I'm still unsuccessfull.

Here's my statement:

```
SELECT `wd`.`id` AS `wdId`,
       `wd`.`serial` AS `wdSerial`,
       `wd`.`serial_ap` AS `wdSerialAp`,
       `wd`.`status` AS `wdStatus`,
       `ex`.`name` AS `expertsName`,
       `ex`.`surname` AS `expertsSurname`,
       `t`.`name` AS `typesName`,
       `o`.`name` AS `ownersName`,
       `t`.`mark` AS `typesMark`,
       `d`.`next_visit` AS `devicesNextVisit`,
       `d`.`id_dev` AS `devicesIdDev`
FROM `warehouse_devices` `wd` LEFT JOIN `experts` `ex` ON `wd`.`expert`=`ex`.`id`
                              LEFT JOIN `types` `t` ON `wd`.`type`=`t`.`id`
                              LEFT JOIN `owners` `o` ON `o`.`id`=`wd`.`owner`
                              LEFT JOIN `devices` `d` ON `d`.`warehouse_devices`=`wd`.`id`
```

Comment: I don't see any if or case statements in that code.

Comment: Hi. What is your question? You don't say what the output is supposed to be given input. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Just include the condition in the `on` clause:

```
FROM `warehouse_devices` `wd` LEFT JOIN
     `experts` `ex`
     ON `wd`.`expert`=`ex`.`id` LEFT JOIN
     `types` `t`
     ON `wd`.`type`=`t`.`id` LEFT JOIN
     `owners` `o`
     ON `o`.`id`=`wd`.`owner` LEFT JOIN
     `devices` `d`
     ON `d`.`warehouse_devices` = `wd`.`id` and wd.install = 1
```

Comment: So simple, so good. Thanks Gordon! PS. But I'm still wondering how I can achieve it without wd.install column.

Answer (score 0):

Try using set operation UNION

you can get records without joining devices table and with joining devices table when `warehouse_devices.install=1`

Query should look like below

```
SELECT `wd`.`id` AS `wdId`,
       `wd`.`serial` AS `wdSerial`,
       `wd`.`serial_ap` AS `wdSerialAp`,
       `wd`.`status` AS `wdStatus`,
       `ex`.`name` AS `expertsName`,
       `ex`.`surname` AS `expertsSurname`,
       `t`.`name` AS `typesName`,
       `o`.`name` AS `ownersName`,
       `t`.`mark` AS `typesMark`,
       ``,
       ``
FROM `warehouse_devices` `wd` LEFT JOIN `experts` `ex` ON `wd`.`expert`=`ex`.`id`
                              LEFT JOIN `types` `t` ON `wd`.`type`=`t`.`id`
                              LEFT JOIN `owners` `o` ON `o`.`id`=`wd`.`owner`

                              UNION

     SELECT `wd`.`id` AS `wdId`,
       `wd`.`serial` AS `wdSerial`,
       `wd`.`serial_ap` AS `wdSerialAp`,
       `wd`.`status` AS `wdStatus`,
       `ex`.`name` AS `expertsName`,
       `ex`.`surname` AS `expertsSurname`,
       `t`.`name` AS `typesName`,
       `o`.`name` AS `ownersName`,
       `t`.`mark` AS `typesMark`,
       `d`.`next_visit` AS `devicesNextVisit`,
       `d`.`id_dev` AS `devicesIdDev`
FROM `warehouse_devices` `wd` LEFT JOIN `experts` `ex` ON `wd`.`expert`=`ex`.`id`
                              LEFT JOIN `types` `t` ON `wd`.`type`=`t`.`id`
                              LEFT JOIN `owners` `o` ON `o`.`id`=`wd`.`owner`
                              LEFT JOIN `devices` `d` ON `d`.`warehouse_devices`=`wd`.`id`  AND wd.install=1
```